# Sine-Gordon (overdamped and forced case)

Tags: partial-differential-equations

The sine-Gordon equation is given by
$$
u_{tt}-u_{xx}+\sin u=0.
$$

What is meant with the *forced and overdamped* sine-Gordon equation?
Maybe that means something like that $u_t$ appeats in the equation (with some damping factor) as well as some RHS $F$, i.e.
$$
u_{tt}+\alpha u_t-u_{xx}+\sin u=F?
$$

Comment: have you tried google?

Comment: Yes, but did not find a satisfying answer

Comment: From where did you pick up the terminology ?

Comment: From some discussions in which the notion of *overdamped forced* sine_Gordon was used but never explained.

Answer (score 1):

The sine-Gordon equation $u_{tt}+\alpha u_t - u_{xx} + d V(u)/du = 0$, where $V(u) = 1-\cos u + F(x) u$, with $F(x)$ being the forcing and $\alpha$ being the damping coefficient, is in the overdamping regime where its long-time solutions are dominated by the diffusion equation $\alpha u_t - u_{xx} + d V(u)/du = 0$.

This regime occurs when $|F|<V$, with the potential $V(u)$ possessing local minima at $u_m+2\pi n$, with small-amplitude modes around the states $u_m$, referred to as overdamped phonons, and large-amplitude solitons (kinks and antikinks) describing the transition from one minimum $u_m$ to an adjacent one $u_m\pm 2\pi$. Usually in this regime there is a critical speed $v_c$ for the solitons such that the kink-antikink collision, both with $v < v_c$, results in their decay into overdamped phonons.

I think that the name "overdamped and forced sine-Gordon equation" has its origin in the derivation of the sine-Gordon equation as the continuum limit of a system of coupled pendula; when every pendulum has damping and forcing the resulting continuous limit is the overdamped and forced sine-Gordon equation. I'm not sure about, but, at least in some cases, the overdamping regime occurs in the limit when the forced pendula are overdamped.